# How to format thousands with dot and decimal with comma

Tags: javascript, regex

How can I format thousands with dot and decimal with comma?

Input: 3197769.7000000007

Expected:
3.197.769,7000000007

I tried the following regex, but it doesn't feel clean enough. I feel like answer should be similar to *[How to format a number with commas as thousands separators?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2901102/how-to-format-a-number-with-commas-as-thousands-separators/2901298#2901298)*, but I don't have enough regex knowledge for it.

```js
const value = 3197769.7000000007
console.log(value.toString().replace(/\B(?<!\.\d*)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, "#").replace('.', ',').replace(/#/g, '.'));
```

Comment: @adiga for those marking as duplicate. please notice regex tag

Comment: It is also marked with javascript and there are native ways to do this than complicated regex

Comment: @Shinjo Not everything needs to be solved with regular expressions. And not everything _should_ or even _can_ be solved with regular expressions.

Comment: In most cases one would use the formatting of [`Intl.NumberFormat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/NumberFormat/NumberFormat) ... `console.log(new Intl.NumberFormat('de-DE', { maximumFractionDigits: 10 }).format('3197769.7000000007'));`

Comment: You have an [xy problem](https://xyproblem.info/) :). A regex is the wrong tool for formatting a number.

Comment: I agree that regex is not the best suited tool since the [Internationalization Web API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl) offers safer and more convenient solutions. Anyhow what I see from the OP's used regex and also from the linked thread, I have to say that there are much cleaner and more straightforward regex and `replace` based solutions like e.g. this one ... [`String(3197769.7000000007).replace('.', ',').replace(/\d(?=(?:(?:\d{3})+),)/g, match => \`${ match }.\`);`](https://regex101.com/r/3pvKHl/1)

Answer (score 2):

I agree that regex is not the best suited tool since the [Internationalization Web API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl) offers safer and more convenient solutions. Anyhow what I see from the OP's used regex and also from the linked thread, I have to say that there are much cleaner and more straightforward regex and `replace` based solutions like e.g. this one ...

```js
console.log(
  '3197769.7000000007 =>',

  String(3197769.7000000007)

    // - replace the standard decimal separator by a comma.
    .replace('.', ',')

    // - see ... [https://regex101.com/r/3pvKHl/1]
    // - replace every digit which is followed
    //   by a sequence of 3-digit groups/blocks
    //   until the comma by the very digit itself
    //   and the thousands block separating dot.
    .replace(/\d(?=(?:(?:\d{3})+),)/g, match => `${ match }.`)
);
console.log(
  '6291563197769.587 =>',

  String(6291563197769.587)
    .replace('.', ',')
    .replace(/\d(?=(?:(?:\d{3})+),)/g, match => `${ match }.`)
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

... where one would

- e.g. cast the number into a string value via the [`String`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/String#string_constructor_and_string_function) function,
- [`replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) the sole occurrence of the decimal delimiter (dot) by a comma,
- `replace` every digit which is followed by a sequence of 3-digit groups/blocks until the comma by the very digit itself and the  thousands block separating dot ...

  - ... with the help of following regex ... [`/\d(?=(?:(?:\d{3})+),)/g`](https://regex101.com/r/3pvKHl/1) where the regex reads as follows ...

    - `/ \d (?= (?:(?:\d{3})+), ) /g` ... **`g`**lobally match a single digit/**`\d`** followed by a [lookahead](https://javascript.info/regexp-lookahead-lookbehind#lookahead)/**`(?= ... )`** where the pattern of the lookahead
    - `(?:(?:\d{3})+) ,` ... enforces a comma which is headed by at least a single block of exactly 3 digits/**`\d{3}`** which also is allowed to become a sequence of blocks of always 3 digits each/**`(?:\d{3})+`**.
    - **Note** ... [the pattern `(?: ... )` is used for grouping where the matching expression is meant to **not** be captured](https://javascript.info/regexp-groups#non-capturing-groups-with).

Comment: Thanks, it works fine for the most part, except when it doesn't have a decimal, it fails to [separate thousands](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rbZjd.png).